# Kibana multi graph

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I am currently using kibana3 and elasticsearch to monitor my system and I'm having trouble to create 3 line charts on the same graph.

Example :

I have the following line :

```
    {
"@version":"1","@timestamp":"2015-02-03T10:06:35.539Z","host":"localhost","plugin":"load","collectd_type":"load","shortterm":0.4,"midterm":0.36,"longterm":0.33
    }
```

On kibana, I can just graph one of these : shortterm, midterm, longterm

I would like to have the 3 of them on the same graph ..

Thx for the help cheers!

Comment: They've promised this in kibana4 (final).

Comment: too bad will wiat for that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you can do this in this [not official kibana3 branch](https://github.com/tvvmb/kibana/tree/betterhistogram).

There's a multifield histogram panel there that allows you to plot different fields, on different queries with different stats(mean, max, min, total, etc').